# Alternative to data URI or sprites?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites, data-uri

I have a bit of a catch 22 situation here. My intention is to save on HTTP requests, which naturally slow the page loading down as the number of requests increases. My first solution was to go for sprites. However, I can't scale a sprite with relative units properly, as it results in parts of one image appearing on another. Then I looked into data URIs. This seemed very promising, until I read that different browsers have (very) different size limitations which could range from a mere few KB, to a few MB.

At the moment, I'm stuck in this situation where I can't choose anything but to go for the old `<img src="image.png">` method.

So question 1: Is there an alternative to sprites and URIs that can achieve a similar goal of reducing requests and speeding up load times?

Question 2: Since the maximum URI size varies, is there some place I can find out which browsers support what sizes? Personally, I don't care for any browsers that are outdated enough to not work with CSS3 and HTML5, so that would be an even bigger help if someone knew anything about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scaling an image sprite with relative units](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865122/scaling-an-image-sprite-with-relative-units)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 `@font-face` rule to define your set of icons you just have to create your own font you can use http://icomoon.io/ for ready set of icons and if you want your own then create Vector of your images (SVG) using illustrator or tool you are good with and import to [icomoon](http://icomoon.io/) create your own font ans save server requests.

**Note**: Need to add all types of font (eg. ttf. woff, svg) as lack of browser support browser picks supported font

CSS to embed created font:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url(sansation_light.woff);/*need to add multiple*/
}
```